# Load in specific rows of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pickle

I have saved a numpy array using `np.savez()` and am opening it with:

```
a = np.load('/file.npz', allow_pickle=True)
a = cp.array(a['arr_0'])
```

But how do I read in specific rows of the array `a`? I know I could access certain rows via `a[x:y]` where x and y are constants such that x<y but I don't want to do that as matrix `a` is very big. Loading in the entire thing each time seems inefficient.

Any help on loading in specific rows between the indices x and y that is faster than loading it in the typical way is much appreciated! An answer suggested using a memmap in the answers but this does not result in improved speed. Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: You should be able to do this by setting the `mmap_mode` of `np.load`.  Something like `a = np.load('/file.npz', allow_pickle=True, mmap_mode='r')`.  Though I'm not too familiar with this option so I couldn't say for sure that it will work for this file format.  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.load.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @KyleParsons, but on https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html#numpy.memmap it says: 
‘r’: Open existing file for reading only.

‘r+’: Open existing file for reading and writing.

‘w+’: Create or overwrite existing file for reading and writing.

‘c’: Copy-on-write: assignments affect data in memory, but changes are not saved to.

I don't think any of these options achieve what I am trying to do

Comment: You say you want to access a row.  Does that not mean reading?  What do you want to do that's not covered by these options?

Comment: To my knowledge reading wouldn't allow me to choose the specific rows between x and y that I would like to open from my saved matrix. Would it @KyleParsons?

Comment: That is what memory mapping does.  It will "open" your whole file, but in this case opening won't be loading it into RAM it will just be pointing to a location on the hard drive.  When you then do something with the array it will load it into RAM, but it can selectively load just a portion into RAM which should be faster and need less RAM.

Answer (score 1):

not sure I got it right but from @KyleParsons comment, I got:

```
import numpy as np
import sys

arr = np.random.randint(0,999,(100,5))

print(arr,'\n ARR SIZE :', sys.getsizeof(arr))


# for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
#     arr_row = np.copy(arr[i])
#     print(i , '  :  ',arr_row)
    
    
np.save('test_100_X_5', arr)    


a = np.load('test_100_X_5.npy', allow_pickle=True, mmap_mode='r')

print('\na : ',type(a), 'SIZE : ',  sys.getsizeof(a),'\n')

for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    a_row = np.copy(a[i])
    print(i , '  :  ',a_row,' size :', sys.getsizeof(a_row))
```

see the size of load object: 'a' vs entire array: 'arr' and singles rows: ('i')

PS

please correct it if I am wrong, I'm trying to learn numpy too

Comment: Ahhh ok thanks I see, so correct me if I'm wrong but this essentially opens the entire matrix but a smaller version (as defined by `sys.getsizeof()`) of it and then I index the row I want, right?.

Comment: I timed how long it takes to load in your `test_100_x_5` array with `mmap_mode='r'` and with the default option. Surprisingly, loading it in with `mmap_mode='r'` took twice as long for your array... It seems this solution may be less efficient than loading in the entire array with `a = np.load('test_100_X_5.npy', allow_pickle=True)` and indexing the column.

Comment: It should take longer to make a mmap array and then read it in one row at a time, but it should be take _less_ time to make a mmap array and read in a single row.

Comment: Do I need to make a copy of the arrays I load in with `np.copy()` to be able to edit them @KyleParsons?

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to edit.  If you want to edit the file on disk, probably the easiest way is to open it in `r+` mode.  Otherwise maybe the least cognitive overhead would be calling `np.copy` or `np.array` on the mmap slice to get a regular in-memory numpy array.

Comment: I though that mmap was useful in terms of reading huge arrays that take up too much memory, so the time issues were not really relevant, same as numpy.memmap

Comment: You seem to be right @pippo1980, it has no impact on the time taken. I tested it on my 60,000 x 10,000 matrix and there is no difference on how long it takes. I guess I should have made this more clear in the question but I am looking for a method that is faster than reading in the whole array.

Comment: is HDF5 faster ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format